# Image Submit Not working in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, form-submit

I have the following code submitting a form

```
<div class="free-download">
   <input name="method_free"
      value="<TMPL_VAR lang_free_download>"
      type="image"
      src="images/free-download.png"
      alt="<TMPL_VAR lang_free_download>" />
</div>
```

it's working fine in firefox, but in internet explorer it just loads the same page for some reason, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are your TMPL_VAR tags stuffing into the HTML?

Comment: I always thought input:image does not submit form by default and onclick JavaScript handler should be used.

Comment: it`s perl, and how do i do an onclick submit form handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `form` attribute in the input tag.

```
<input type="image" form="(ID of the form it belongs to)">
```

Sometimes inputs can get lost in layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see if you are getting method_free_x and method_free_y posted back to you? Seems when using an image to submit, you get the X and Y coordinates that were clicked.